# How can we use pgSQL in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: c#, postgresql, automationanywhere

I have created `DLL` using pgSQL(to read data and return to Automation Anywhere) and I am trying to use it in an Automation anywhere bot. But it shows an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'npgsql, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. System cannot find the file specified.

if you have any idea to solve that please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing all(copy paste) the necessary assemblies ( DLLs) that are required for pgSQL in your DLL function to be invoked into AAE Program files directory. Since Player couldn't load the dependencies of your dll It is throwing this exception.

Another place where you can copy is while running bot see where your dll is located  and put all necessary dependent assemblies there When you run your metabot AAE creates temporary folder where it copy your dll. copy dependencies there

Comment: Thank you. I tried after adding all dll assembies, but it gives same error.

Comment: Try registering those assemblies in GAC

Comment: yea i have tried it. but it was not supportive. is there any driver to install in machine to use pgsql within another applications other than pgadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependencies you used whilst creating the DLL into the metabot as well, by uploading them alongside your DLL in the assets view. In this case 'npgsql.dll'.

If you've built the DLL on another machine, you can - in addition to the steps above - also try adding the dependent DLLs to the PATH.